# Не получается вернуть результат функции express JS

Tags: node.js

не могу вернуть результат выполнения функции в бэк энде, и отправить его на фронт энд.
Использую библиотеку express JS и Easy VK.
Вот мой код

```
  app.post('/auth', jsonParser, (req, res,) => {
    login = req.body.login;
    password = req.body.password;
    authorize(login, password);
  })

 function authorize(login, password) {
    easyvk({
      username: login,
      password: password
    }).then(async (vk) => {
        try {
            let info = await vk.call('account.getProfileInfo', {})
            console.log(info.getFullResponse().response)
           } catch(e) {
               console.log(e)
           }
        })
     }
```

Если ошибка происходит то только в методе easyvk(). Например не верный логин, пароль. Как мне отправить это на фронт? Пробовал использовать

```
   app.post('/auth', jsonParser, (req, res,) => {
    login = req.body.login;
    password = req.body.password;
    try {
        authorize(login, password);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Не верный логин");
  })
```

Если данные не верны, то `console.log("Не верный логин");` не срабатывает.

Comment: Нужно из функции `authorize` вернуть промис и работать с этим промисом

Comment: @andreymal, помоги реализовать, не совсем понимаю ( так как учусь

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/auth', jsonParser, async(req, res,) => {
    const login = req.body.login;
    const password = req.body.password;

    try {
        const response = await authorize(login, password);
        res.json({ status: true, response });
    } catch(error) {
        res.json({ status: false, error: error.message });
    }
})

async function authorize(username, password) {
    const vk = await easyvk({ username, password });
    const info = await vk.call('account.getProfileInfo');
    
    const response = info.getFullResponse().response;
    
    Promise.resolve(response);
}
```

Comment: у меня ругается что `const response = await authorize(login, password);
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо.
Помогло решение с Promise.

```
authorize(login, password).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
  }).catch(console.error);


async function authorize(login, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    easyvk({ 
      username: login, 
      password: password,
     }).then(async (vk) => {
        let info = await vk.call('account.getProfileInfo', {})
        console.log(info.getFullResponse().response)
        resolve(info)
     }).catch(error => {
        reject(error)
     })
  })
}
```